# Discord.Js - Uncaught DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

When I try to reply to a user with a bot in DM's, I get this error: Discord.Js - Uncaught DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user

What's the problem?

Code:

```
client.on('message', message=>{

    
    if(!message.author.send('$$')) return

    if(message.author.send('$$')){
        
        message.channel.send('Hi! Please describe your message to get help with it.').catch(error => {
            message.channel.send('I was unable to send a message.')
        })
    }
```

Comment: They either blocked you or are not accepting dms from non-friends

Comment: I allowed the messages and it's still showing this error...

Answer (score 1):

This API error is returned if the user does not accept DMs from accounts that are not in his friends list, blocked etc. Just catch that error and everything will function as it is supposed to - this is not a bug, but a discord API feature.

Edit: There also appears to be a problem with the code itself, it is missing some brackets:

```js
client.on('message', message=> {

    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(!message.author.send('$$')) return;

    if(message.author.send('$$')){
        
        message.channel.send('Hi! Please describe your message to get help with it.').catch(error => {
            message.channel.send('I was unable to send a message.')
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you - it worked. The problem is that BOT keeps spamming the message ('Hi, Please describe your message to get help with it.')

Comment: That is because the code is telling the bot to send a message any time the user sends a message, it does not ignore the messages from the bot and creates a loop where the bot registers their own message and replies to it. You can prevent this by adding " if (message.author.bot) return; ", I will edit the original post code.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help :)